# How to pass information from JSF to javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, embed

Hi I'm developing a small web app in which I have and embed video player,

```
<object width="500" height="295" id="undefined" name="undefined"
data="http://www.facebook.com/l/c816a6KvMcY-i-   yv0MPzf7OgOAw;releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="movie"   value="http://www.facebook.com/l/c816aYgPeP5dGgJdnVHVdFuuEvA;releases.flowplayer.org/swf/fl    owplayer- 3.2.5.swf" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"url":"../resources/<%=????%>"},
"playlist":[{"url":"../resources/<%=????%>"}]}'/>
</object>
```

My problem is how to pass the selected movie trailer to de player, since the selected movie is handled by JSF to get to the trailer (the I'm using strings the file is already in correct location)

```
<h:outputText value="Trailer:"/>
<h:outputText value="#{ http://www.facebook.com/l/c816a-   u4g9I3Gob02P5T8CTSmQg;movies.movies.trailer}" title="Trailer" />
```

Thank you very much for any information you can provide
best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print it inline.

If JSP:

```
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"url":"../resources/<h:outputText value="#{bean.clip}" />"}, 
    "playlist":[{"url":"../resources/<h:outputText value="#{bean.url}" />"}]}'/>
```

If Facelets:

```
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"url":"../resources/#{bean.clip}"},
    "playlist":[{"url":"../resources/#{bean.url}"}]}'/>
```

Comment: It is not working player outputs Stream not found, [Clip] http://localhost:8080/jsfmovieplayer/faces/movie/../resources/<td> <td>halo.mp4</td><tr><td>

Comment: Rightclick page in browser, choose *View Source*, what do you see? Is it correct? If not, alter server side JSF code accordingly so that it generates the correct HTML.

Comment: The player code si not showing at all, I don-t know why? what should I alter?

Comment: If the `<object>` with `<param>` et al does at its whole own not appear at all in the HTML, then the problem lies elsewhere, at higher levels. I can't help you further based on the information given as far.

Comment: Please if possible tell me what information should I provide, this is a very simple CRUD application JSF (JSP) from a MySQL db. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'd suggest to put JSF aside, create a plain HTML file for pure testing purposes, put the necessary HTML code in it with all hardcoded values. Once you get that to work, copy the necessary HTML back in a minimial JSP/XHTML file. When that still works, substitute the hardcoded values by dynamic values using outputtext or EL. When that still works, put the piece back in the bigger JSP/XHTML file where it should belong. Whenever you stucks at a specific stage, report back. By the way, are you using JSP or Facelets? If JSP, which JSF version?

Comment: JSP, and JSF 2.0 it works if a set the name of the video file myself value='config={"clip":{"url":"../resources/myvideo.mp4"}"},"playlist":[{"url":"../resources/myvideo.mp4"}]}'/> WORKS like a charm but when I pass the ref with jsf it fails

Comment: OK, what JSF code have you then and what do you see in the generated HTML? On JSP you should be using `h:outputText` to print it.

Comment: <object id="flowplayer" width="800" height="460"
data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> 
<param name="movie" value="../resources/</td>
<td>halo.mp4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":"../resources/</td>
<td>halo.mp4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>"}'/>
The page source code

Comment: So the bean property value contains those HTML td and tr elements? Why does it contain HTML? It should only contain "halo.mp4", not "</td> <td>halo.mp4</td> </tr> <tr> <td>".

Comment: I don't know but h:command is putting out that, no css, no nothing changeing that, have you heard of something like this?

Comment: h:command? You should use `<h:outputText value="#{bean.clip}"/>` and nothing else in there. If necessary update your question to include the minimum JSP/JSF code which reproduces this problem.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake I'm using h:outputText update just need to get the #{bean.clip} working. Do know another video player more suitted for this? or a better way?

Comment: It look much like that this code is been placed inside a `h:panelGrid` and you didn't properly group the cells by `h:panelGroup`. For that we need to see the JSP/JSF code.

Comment: It workedd!!!! you were right it was the h:panelGrid!!! Thank you vey much Balus!!!! you are the man